# Sonar not showing code coverage after jenkin's build

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

We have a multi module maven project. We are using *jacoco* for code coverage analysis. I prepared the pom file to run the test cases and pick up the code coverage. When i build the project on my local i can see the code coverage on the *sonar dashboard*.

After pushing the changes to the github and when jenkins build got triggered the code coverage is not available on the sonar dashboard. I found the following error in the jenkins build logs:

> Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?

How can I make the code coverage available after the successful jenkins build?

Comment: What commands is run by your jenkins to build your project ? is that command the same as the one you run on your local machine ? can you find the jacoco report generated by jenkins build in the jenkins workspace ?

Comment: Can you post a more detailed log so we can see what was happening. Also, why are you using Jacoco seperately from SonarQube? SonarQube has Jacoco built into it for its own code coverage metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that while compiling Java or Groovy etc code, the debug option is turned on. I use Gradle (instead of Maven) and to enable debug option, I do something like this in **Gradle**. You can put the following code in project's build.gradle OR top level $GRADLE_HOME/init.d/some-global.gradle file (inside allprojects { ... } section).

```
   tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
     options.debug = true
     options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
   }

   tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
        options.debug = true
   }
```

Do the same in Maven (how to turn debug option on using -g for Java and true for Groovy based projects).

After this, all you need is make sure your sonar.xx.yyy variables are set correctly while calling sonar runner (i.e. sonarRunner task in Gradle).

I set those variables as (UT for Unit tests, IT for Integration Tests). IT code coverage will be generated only if you attach jacocoagent.jar to the Tomcat/external JVM (instead of what Gradle/Maven JVM is) which runs your application's .war/.ear file.

```
-Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec 
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec
```

There are other sonar.xx.yy variables you can see online/docs.

In Maven, you can turn Java debug on using this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel> 
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```